# Unable to Mirror Dual Displays Centos 7

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, centos, hdmi

I have a Centos 7 system with an Nvidia Quadro K620 card that has a display port and a DVI output.  I have a small display on the DVI output and an Ultra-HD display on the display port through a DP to HDMI adapter.

I went to settings - display settings to configure my monitors and they both show up with the ability to set resolution and rotation but I don't see anything that allows mirroring the monitors.  The monitors are spanning each other.

I also opened the Nvidia-settings GUI in /usr/bin and also there is no setting for mirroring the monitors.

I am familiar with RHEL not centos and in RHEL there is a clickable box that allows mirroring monitors.

How do I mirror an HDTV Monitor(3480x,1950) from Display Port with a HP monitor (1920x1200) on the DVI port through an Nvidia K620 quadro card using Centos 7 (Without having to drop down to a common lower resolution)?

**xrandr --output DVI-I1 --same-as DP-0**      Mirrors for a local account but will revert to spanning on reboot or any other account.
Thanks

Comment: OK-I was able to mirror when I dropped down to 1920x1080 resolution on BOTH monitors and I used xrandr --output DVI-I1 --same-as DP-0

Comment: I really want the UltraHD resolution on the 60" and to mirror without having to buy an UltraHD monitor for the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The
[NVIDIA Quadro K620 specs](http://www4.pny.com/MarketingPromotions/ResellerProgram/NVIDIA%20Quadro%20K620%20Product%20Page%20-%20Web.pdf) say :

> Maximum DVI-I DL Resolution 2560 x 1600 at 60Hz

The conclusion is that you cannot display 3480x1950 via DVI.

You will need to use two DisplayPort cables utilizing the
DisplayPort 1.2 new multistreaming capabilities to do "Daisy chaining",
and so your HP monitor needs to support DisplayPort input.

If the HP monitor does not accept DisplayPort input, you will need
to get an [MST hub](https://www.startech.com/faq/mst-hubs-what-is-an-mst-hub) :

[image]

This is how you "Daisy chain" two DisplayPort monitors, by connecting
DisplayPort labeled "Out" from monitor 1 to the DisplayPort labeled "In"
on the second monitor.

[image]

There are many checks that you will have to do to verify the validity
of any combination of hardware that you will buy.
(Be aware that product recommendations are not allowed here.)

Comment: So buying an ultra HD monitor to replace the computer monitor would not have worked because the DVI wouldn't support it.

Comment: A UHD monitor could work by Daisy chaining it on the DisplayPort, so having two UHD monitors on the same port. This should work in theory, but in practice it depends on the involved software+hardware capabilities and implementations of all devices including adapters. I would suggest only buying the second UHD monitor from a seller with a return policy, just in case.